# How do I use add-on Simple Curves to chamfer point?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I would like to be able to make a round corner on a curve similar to chamfer in 4D, like a smoothly bent tube? I've found and added the add-on Simple Curves but don't know how to do it? Or maybe I don't need the add-on?

Comment: Use the [Bevel Tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/bevel.html?highlight=bevel) or the [Bevel Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/bevel.html?highlight=bevel). Also when referring to tools from other programs it helps if you show images that illustrate the function you are looking for.

Comment: @cegaton both tools only work on meshes, not on Bezier curve points.

Comment: Pretty cool, didn't know this addon, it as some useful tools.

Comment: @cegaton You right, that's another way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about this [Simple Curves](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Curve/Simple_curves) add-on:

First of all Install add-on from file, check it to have it enabled and Save settings.

[image]

1. In **Edit Mode** find **Misc** tab in **Tool Shelf**.
2. Select **Curve** point.
3. Choose **Fillet**.
4. Tweak **Radius**.

[image: final]

Comment: I don't see the Misc option.

Comment: @PalBergstrom check my edit.

Comment: Thanks but I don't see it. Maybe it doesn't work in 2,79.

Comment: @PalBergstrom I'll need you to show me some screenshots. I've also 2.79 and everything is working as you can see above. Double check which add-on you have activated Simple Curve or Simple Curves? Check again the one from my edit.

Comment: Works. That was it. I confused them. Thank you for your help.